# Parse html text from xml with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have an xml that has a node with text with some html characters:

```
<text>Trobafa assles &lt;b&gt;cheaentrades cona El último tributode la geiad de la  Fa&lt;/b&gt;
```

When I parse it with jquery as a text(kind of this):

```
$(this).parent().find('text').text();
```

It show characters as text like this
(`"Trobafa assles '<br/>'..."`).
Whic is Right.
But What if I want to parse it and ouput as html?

I've tried this:

```
$(this).parent().find('text').html();
```

But it doesn't work at all.....

Comment: it returns jquery error

Comment: What error? Can you set up an example in http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the XML file as HTML:

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET", url: 'file.xml', dataType: "html", success: 
         function(xml) { ....
```